# java - How identify which button was clicked and change pic?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

I have an array of buttons and I need to load a file of data into that array which I have already done so but then I need to identify which button was clicked and change the pic of the button. For example, if the text on the button is C or B then set the image to A.png if is * then set it to B.png
this is what I have:

```
JButton[][] button = new JButton[10][10];
public static void main(String[] args) {
     for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
          for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
               button[i][j] = new JButton("");
               button[i][j].setActionCommand("" + cpuBoard[i][j].getText());
               button[i][j].addActionListener(new game());
          }
     }
} 
// load a file of text into each button - already done so 

private static class game implements ActionListener {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
           String action = event.getActionCommand();
           if (action.equals("C") || action.equals("B")) {
                event.setIcon(new ImageIcon("A.png"));
           } else (action.equals("*")) {
                event.setIcon(new ImageIcon("B.png"))
    }
}
```

Comment: *"this is what I have"* - Yes, and what's wrong with it?

Comment: Class names should start with an upper case character. Have you ever seen a class in the JDK that doesn't? Follow Java conventions. Also, there is no need to create 100 listeners. You can create a single listener (outside your loops) and add the same listener to each button.

Answer (score 1):

An ActionEvent stores the component that the event occured on (the event's source). In this case, the event stores the JButton that was clicked. You can retrieve this information by using `getSource`:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    JButton clickedButton = (JButton) event.getSource();
```

Then you invoke `setIcon` on the JButton instance.

Comment: Since the OP is seeding the `actionCommand` property of the button, this seems like an unnecessary step backwards

Comment: @MadProgrammer, I'm not understanding your comment. The ActionListener doesn't have a setIcon() method (which is what the OP is trying to do) so you need to get the button from the ActionEvent so you can change the Icon of the button. (1+)

Comment: @camickr [face palm]